# Laravel: Grouping of rows

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a model called `Order` like so:

```
class Order extends Model
{
     public function offer()
     {
     return $this->belongsTo(Offer::class);
     }  
}
```

Example rows may look like this

```
id  quantity    offer_id
15  5           20
20  1           21
25  3           20
30  2           27
35  1           20
40  1           21
```

I want to group all orders by `offer_id` using Laravel Eloquent to give the following output:

```
[
    [20] => [
        // order 15,
        // order 25,
        // order 35,
    ],
    [21] => [
        // order 20,
        // order 40,
    ]
    [27] => [
        // order 30,
    ]
]
```

How can I do this efficiently? I have tried the following:

```
Order::groupBy('offer_id)->get();
```

But this just hides orders with the same `offer_id`.

Note that I will ideally like to do this all in Laravel Elqouent, so opposed to doing some post-processing.

Comment: How about `Order::get()->groupBy('offer_id')`, this edits the collection after it has been fetched but does what you want (as [documented here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#available-methods)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The laravel collection method `groupBy` does exactly this.

> The groupBy method groups the collection's items by a given key:

```
$orders = Order::get()->groupBy('offer_id');
```

This works since the query builder returns a collection, you can chain the collection helpers onto this object to get the desired outcome.

Documentation found on the [Laravel site](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-has)